# Burned B2 USB protection diode in Arduino Nano with supplied circuit

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, circuit-protection

with the supplied circuit I managed to burn the B2 USB protection of my Arduino Nano.
When both, the Arduino Nano clone and the Wemos D1 mini clone were connected via separate usb cables, everything worked as expected. As soon as I hooked them up in "parallel" on a known good 5.1V power supply, the diode went to the 9th dimension.
Can anybody tell me why ?
[image]

Edit :
I was unclear : circuit worked, when both (Nano & Wemos D1 mini clone) were powered via separate usb cables. All devices (EEPRom etc) powered from Arduino (3.3V & 5V Pins). Arduino and Wemos have RX=>TX, TX=>RX & GND connected.
Without changing anything else on the working breadboard, I then unplugged both usb cables and tried to power everything via 5V from an external 5.1V bench power supply. when I did that, the usb protection diode on the Nano blew, without the Nano actually being connected via USB.
From my understanding, everything should just be parallel on the 5V rail and as long as the power supply can deliver enough current, it should be fine. But it wasn`t.

After taking off the blown diode and bridging it, all parts work (powered by 2 separate usb cables) again.

There is not much chance, that there was a short really, as everything worked before and I only added the 5v and GND wires.

Thanks a lot in advance ! regards, Oliver

Comment: Assuming  you plugged the cable into the Nano, a short from +5V to ground would do it.

Comment: Would you post the schematics around the part that blew up? B2 on Arduino?

Comment: well I wasnt clear enough I am sorry - when I attached both devices to a 5.1V power supply (like in the circuit in the picture) i didnt attach usb cable to any device of course.
I had it all working and running with usb cables instead of powering via 5V rail, but everything else just exactly the same. Then I removed both usb cables and attached the 5V & GND rails of my breadboard to the power supply. then B2 went boom

Comment: @Justme
Unfortunately I dont have a schematics of this nano clone, probably there is one around somewhere.
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29703/smoke-came-out-of-arduino-nano
It is that usb protection diode mentioned in the linked thread. After I took it off and bridged it with a cable, it works again (while waiting for new diode)